# Monero transaction rpc call doesn't return any result for the payment ID

Tags: rpc, payment-id, monero-wallet-rpc

I have a monero address (say ABC) with some balance in it.
I need to initiate a transaction to the same ABC address with different payment ID (16 bit) to differentiate for a purpose. 
I did the transaction and using **incomingTransfers** rpc call i found the tx hash and in xmrchain i see the transaction placed. 
But using monero **getBulkPayments** json rpc call with the above mentioned payment ID, I could not retrieve the transaction details for the particular payment ID (16 bit).
How could i find that transaction?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you passing in a hex encoded payment id?

Comment: I have used a payment ID which was returned from splitIntegratedAddress call..

Comment: Returned payment ID is of 16 characters long.

Comment: Try get_bulk_payments without supplying the payment id parameter to confirm you are passing in the correctly encoded hex string. The payment id string parameter is supposed to be hex encoded and my guess is you are passing in an unencoded string.

Comment: Update your question with your sample calls and results for both RPC requests.

Comment: If i tried get_bulk_payments without payment ID, am getting only the transaction which has payment ID '000000...0', that transaction was happened without adding payment ID. So that's fine, but other transactions not listing.

Comment: And so what do you get in monero-wallet-cli for show_transfers? Does it show up there? If not the transfer did not happen.

Comment: Yes, with show_transfers command i can get that transfer details. But not in getBulkPayments!